# Dynamically altering Silverlight control width/height does not work in Firefox

Tags: silverlight, firefox

I have a Silverlight control that auto resizes based on its content as well as when the browser window is resized. You can see it working in IE at http://www.scottmarlowe.com (it's the tag cloud on the right).

I know you have to define the height style to 100% in FF just to get the control to display.

It seems that setting the width and height style properties as below do not take in FF. In the C# code-behind for the Silverlight control I have:

```
silverlightObjectTag.SetStyleAttribute ("width", divWidth + "px");
```

and, for the height:

```
silverlightObjectTag.SetStyleAttribute ("height", uxWrapPanel.ActualHeight + "px");
```

Neither of these work in FF.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this. I'm still working out the details, and I need to test regression against IE, but it's looking better.